# Angular export Excel client side

Tags: excel, angular, typescript

I'm using Angular v4, i guess how can I build an Excel spreadsheet starting from an object in a component. I need to download the Excel file on the click of a button and I have to do this client side. I have a json file composed of arrays and I need to transfer this on an excel file, possibly customizable in style. Is it possible? If yes, how?

Edit:
No js libraries please, need to do this with Typescript and Angular

Comment: is .csv acceptable or it has to be an xls file?

Comment: I necessarly need an xls file

Comment: What aspects of the xls file are you hoping to use that csv won't work? csv will launch with the Excel program. Do you need multiple sheets, functions, etc?

Comment: you can use JSZip library in typescript. https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/examples.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

yourdata= jsonData

```
ConvertToCSV(objArray) {
            var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
              var str = '';
            var row = "";

            for (var index in objArray[0]) {
                //Now convert each value to string and comma-separated
                row += index + ',';
            }
            row = row.slice(0, -1);
            //append Label row with line break
            str += row + '\r\n';

            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                var line = '';
                for (var index in array[i]) {
                    if (line != '') line += ','

                    line += array[i][index];
                }
                str += line + '\r\n';
            }
            return str;
        }
```

in your html:

```
<button (click)="download()">export to excel</button>
```

in component:

```
download(){    
 var csvData = this.ConvertToCSV(yourdata);
                        var a = document.createElement("a");
                        a.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
                        document.body.appendChild(a);
                        var blob = new Blob([csvData], { type: 'text/csv' });
                        var url= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                        a.href = url;
                        a.download = 'User_Results.csv';/* your file name*/
                        a.click();
                        return 'success';
}
```

Hope you it will help you

Comment: Hello paruvelly,
I am using your code, the file is downloaded successfully but can't open in excel sheet.
Error - Can't open file
This version of office can't support the file.

Do you have any idea why such error is coming?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: does anyone knows how to add custom header other that the json value as header?

Answer (score 1):

Vishwanath answer was working for me when i replaced "," with ";". In Typescript the implementation could look like this:

```
ConvertToCSV(objArray: any) {
    const array = typeof objArray !== 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
    let str = '';
    let row = '';

    for (const index of Object.keys(objArray[0])) {
      row += `${index};`;
    }
    row = row.slice(0, -1);
    str += `${row}\r\n`;

    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      let line = '';
      for (const index of Object.keys(array[i])) {
        if (line !== '') {
          line += ';';
        }
        line += array[i][index];
      }
      str += `${line}\r\n`;
    }
    return str;
  }
```

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will not get that done without js libraries in the background. **What you need are the typings for utilizing it in your Angular project with typescript.**

For creating an excel file you could use something like [exceljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs). To use it in your project also install the typings you can find [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/exceljs). I am not sure if this library fits... haven't used it before.

For downloading you should use [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) (I have already used it).

```
npm install file-saver --save
```

... and the typings:

```
npm install @types/file-saver --save-dev
```

For using FileSaver.js put the following import to your component:

```
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
```

To trigger the download use that:

```
FileSaver.saveAs(fileData, "filename.xlsx")
```

'fileData' has to be a Blob.

Hope this helps a little.

Comment: Vishwanath's code works just fine, with the changes mentioned by user3588429. It's simple and effective, without the need for JS libraries

Answer (score -2):

it not is possible.

XLS is a binary format.

The project Apache POI(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_POI)  name class as HSSF (Horrible SpreadSheet Format).

my recommendation, make it in server side.