# how to export data from angular table to excel with pagination

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angular

i want to export my table data from angular to excel(.xls) i have try this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var tableToExcel = (function() {
            var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
                , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
                , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
                , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
            return function(table, name) {
                if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
                var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
                window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
            }
        })()
    </script>
```

My button

```
 <input type="button" onclick="tableToExcel('testTable', 'W3C Example Table')" value="Export to Excel">
```

My table

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="testTable">
   //data in table with pagination//
</table>
```

But it's export only 1 page. and i want to export data all page from pagination

Comment: Similar here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44110009/angular-export-excel-client-side

Comment: @Ludwig i can't understand the answer of the older post